# IBM Worklight 6.0 - app deployment fails with the error "unable to process the request"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have built a basic application. I have also updated `connectOnStartup` to true, added `WL.Client.connect()` in `wlCommonInit()` and updated `worklight.properties`:

```
publicWorkLightHostname=92.1.52.17
publicWorkLightProtocol=http
publicWorkLightPort=9080
```

The build was successful except for these errors in the development console:

```
[err] 0  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/C:

/Documents%20and%20Settings/wl/Bureau/workspaces/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
    [err] 94  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - Starting OpenJPA 1.2.2
    [err] 94  WorklightPU  INFO   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.jdbc.JDBC - Using dictionary class "org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.HSQLDictionary".
    [err] 0  WorklightReportsPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightReportsPU', root URL [file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/wl/Bureau/workspaces/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
```

I have deployed the app manually to the liberty profile, and added the .wlapp to the console.
When starting the app in common from the console I get an error stating that the server was "unable to process the request".

The javascript console show:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a step back.

Worklight 6.0 is already running on Liberty, so what do you mean by "deployed the app manually to the liberty profile"?

1. Are you in fact trying to transfer your app to another application server? Please edit the question WITH ALL INFORMATION and steps and IBM Information Center topics you have followed for doing so.
2. Why do you change the port in worklight.properties? If you change the port of the project you should also change the port of the application server you intend to deploy it on. Make sure the ports match(!).
3. Also note that if you already set `connectOnStartup` to `true`, then there is absolutely no need for you to also add WL.Client.connect...

As for the error messages you have pointed out - these are harmless, and have been removed in 6.0.0.1 I believe. Make sure you are running the latest version of Worklight. If they are still there for you, then they are just removed internally and will be gone in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer. I restart a new liberty profile server and use ant to deploy the war file. 
In the studio i have used right clic on app and

> build all

instead of

> build for remote server

that was my mistake and it works fine now.
I have compare the .wlapp but i'm not sure if they are different.
thanks